# load field from foreign-key related table as a native type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have 2 Tables:

```
Customer
    Id int
    Name varchar
    TypeId int

CustomerType
    Id int
    Type varchar
```

TypeId is a foreign key to CustomerType's Id. Now how can I load the Customer as such an entity with EF:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Type would be the Type attribute from CustomerType. I am using code-first with EF5. It does currently not work, I keep getting the `The navigation property X is not a declared property on type..`  exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map property to separate table. Only entities could be mapped to tables. As workaround you can create property, with type of `CustomerType` which will be mapped to second table, and mark `Type` property as not mapped:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    protected CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Type 
    { 
        get { return CustomerType.Type; }
        set { CustomerType.Type = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: so there is no way to do it without creating a separate entity for it?

Comment: @user1151923 yes, you can't map property to separate table. Only entities could be mapped to tables

Comment: gah, EF is so darn inflexible it borders on not being usable in many cases for me..

Comment: @user1151923 yep, silly inheritance support (no eager loading for derived type's memebers), no enums before .NET 4.5, no updates for graphs, etc..